# How to play html5 video? When the file is file.m4v?

Tags: php, javascript, linux, html, html5-video

I have tried several methods but none is playing the file2.m4v using html5 see screen shot.

But if i use that same file using VLC/Mplayer it play the film nicely (no problem). Please see following the code and the file detail information's to find the code's its using:

[image]

## video.php:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

  <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" controls>
    <source 
        src="/var/www/html/video/file2.m4v" 
            type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>    
  </video>

</body>
</html>
```

## Find the file audio/video codecs:

```
$ mplayer -vo null -ao null -frames 0 -identify file2.m4v
MPlayer SVN-r33251-4.6.0 (C) 2000-2011 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing file2.m4v.
TS file format detected.
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
TS_PARSE: COULDN'T SYNC
VIDEO MPEG4(pid=69) AUDIO AAC(pid=68) NO SUBS (yet)!  PROGRAM N. 1
ID_VIDEO_ID=69
ID_AUDIO_ID=68
FPS not specified in the header or invalid, use the -fps option.
Load subtitles in ./
ID_FILENAME=file2.m4v
ID_DEMUXER=mpegts
ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=0x10000004
ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=0
ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=352
ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=288
ID_VIDEO_FPS=0.000
ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=0.0000
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=MP4A
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=0
ID_AUDIO_RATE=0
ID_AUDIO_NCH=0
PROGRAM_ID=1 (0x01), PMT_PID: 66(0x42)
ID_START_TIME=28315.35
ID_LENGTH=0.00
ID_SEEKABLE=1
ID_CHAPTERS=0
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
Unsupported PixelFormat 61
Unsupported PixelFormat 53
Selected video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
==========================================================================
ID_VIDEO_CODEC=ffodivx
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 8000 Hz, 1 ch, s16le, 0.0 kbit/0.00% (ratio: 0->16000)
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=0
ID_AUDIO_RATE=8000
ID_AUDIO_NCH=1
Selected audio codec: [ffaac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio))
==========================================================================
AO: [null] 8000Hz 1ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
ID_AUDIO_CODEC=ffaac
Starting playback...


Exiting... (End of file)
ID_EXIT=EOF
```

What else i can use to play this file in the browser? Is there any javascript player available also in case html5 cant play it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML5 Video is just a convention to play a certain video formats with a new element for which browsers will implement an own player. HTML5 won’t provide players or something like that.

You have to look for the codecs and contained supported by most browsers, which, if I remember well, are mostly Theora for Video and Vorbis for audio, in an OGG container.

Then I remember that Webkit browsers will support Matroska (MKV) containers using V8 as video codec and Vorbis for audio.

**My recommendation:** provide an OGG file with Theora and Vorbis as video and audio codecs respectively. Inside provide a fallback using an MKV file with V8 and Vorbis and then, if you can, inside an MPG video file using Mpeg2 and MP2 (couldn’t think on something better) as video and audio codecs, fallback.
Then as the last fallback, a Flash player playing a FLV video file.

**Example for how your HTML should look like:**

```
<video src="thevideo.ogg">
    <video src="firstFallback.mkv">
        <object type="video/mpeg" src="secondFallback.mpeg">
            <object
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                src="player.swf?etc...">
                <p>Download <a href="videourl">the video etc...</a><br />
                or use a more modern browser to watch online, etc...</p>
            </object>
        </object>
    </video>
</video>
```

Etc... ;-)

With this configuration, most (if not all) browsers should be able to play your video, preferring the most supported (and most modern) format. “Fallbacking” until they find a Flash Player.

**For hints on what formats to support:** take a look at [the HTML5 Video part in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Supported_video_formats).

**Important:** In your code you are refering to an absolute filesystem path, which is totally not-accesible for a web visitor. Maybe in the **src** you meant `/video/file2.m4v`.

Comment: There is no directory issues. I replaced with another file such as file.avi and it works. But not this file.

Comment: @LearnFedora if you are serving the file on your own computer it will work, but for a visitor it won’t. Because the src attribute will be, in their case, referring to a file in their computer.

Comment: @LearnFedora take a look at my answer now, I added a link in the end.

Comment: Let me make it transparent. The video is getting captured from one AXIS camera which is a RTSP stream. So using VLC i am saving it as MP4 (mpeg4 as video, aac as audio). I can only play it with Linux and other media players. But i cant play it in browser such as HTML5, nor i can convert Realtime to OGG (vorbis audio, because VLC is broken has bug if i use ogg or other formats).

Comment: HTML5 standard is ogg, mp4, webm, ok fine. But i cant convert RTSP stream to those, because tools such as VLC is broken if i use ogg mux or webm mux. Only i can use mp4 mux to have audio/video. But if i make that it still does not play with this either: <embed name="RAOCXplayer" src="file.mp4" width="320" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" AutoSize="false" EnableContextMenu="0" DisplaySize="0">

Comment: @LearnFedora again, HTML5 is not a player, it depends on the browser implementation. Is this meant for web visitors? If so, consider making the stream available in a more appropriate codec for this with ffserver. (I have done this before, so I think this solution is good for you)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4112/discussion-between-mario-and-learnfedora)

Comment: V8? what's that? i only know a javascript engine of that name. is it a video codec too?

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="300" height="200" preload="auto" src="/var/www/html/video/file2.m4v" type="video/mp4" autoplay controls></video>
```

Also try renaming the file to file2.mp4

Comment: Your sure the file does not have Apple's FairPlay DRM protection, and the reason for it playing locally is that your computer has iTunes installed. Also it seems the path to the file is somewhat strange? Your log says : "mplayer: No such file or directory", but it certainly looks like it found the file to me, but the length and bitrate is zero !

Comment: Did you download this video from iTunes?

Comment: its not downloaded file. Its self created file from VLC player. Its nothing to do with iTunes.

Comment: Then why on earth did you name it .m4v wich is a specific Apple file extension for iTunes, and not .mp4 ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is a web standard (in other words, a specification), not a technology, so the phrase "html5 cant play it" implies a bit of misunderstanding on your part. The file is decoded by the browser according to the settings you specify in the `<video>` tag. It is worth noting that not every browser and/or operating system has the same codecs available, so first verify that you can play the video natively.

Firefox, for one, cannot decode anything encoded with the H.264 codec, which I believe is used in .m4v files (anyone who knows better, please correct me).

Lastly, as someone else pointed out, your path is likely wrong. Remove the 'var' and 'www' portions of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is correct, so either the path is incorrect, the file is invalid, or the browser doesn't support m4v.

1. /var/www/ is highly suspicious, but as you say it works with a avi file, so that is not it
2. Try using the file: http://ade.apple.com/movies/institute2011/hotel.m4v in the src. If it is playing, then your m4v is probably not correctly encoded.
3. If you are using Firefox or Opera then the movie will never play, as they don't support anything other than WebM and OGG