# HTML video turns green and won't play. How can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, video

When I open the code, the video is tinted green and does not play. (This is for a school activity.)

```css
.video {
  width: 700px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<video src="http://triosdevelopers.com/~J.Riz/Lighthouse/lighthouse.m4v" class="video" autoplay></video>
```

Comment: The snippet I made you works for me (VERY LOUD!!!!)

Comment: It doesn't play in Chrome MacOS. Just the poster image displays with no media controls. Edit: actually, it was my adblocker preventing playback.

Comment: Hey @Turnip, consider closing your question if your issue is now solved!

Comment: @Puka This isn't my question.

Comment: Sorry @Turnip, my bad, I read your comment too quickly!

Comment: Hay @anon, what browser are you using? Have you tried another browser?

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a trouble with playing a m4v file. Check out this post:

[How to play html5 video? When the file is file.m4v?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698953/how-to-play-html5-video-when-the-file-is-file-m4v)

To test this, look for a tool to convert from m4v to mp4. search online for: "m4v to mp4 coverter online" (to covert a file you probably most download the video first)
If you CBA with this, just choose another video, preferably an mp4